# Check <div> text Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, watir

I'm writing a script using Ruby and Watir that needs to print the result of a coin flip. The HTML looks like this when you win:

```
<div id="result" style="" class="center">
      <div id="win" class="bold center">You win!</div>
      <div id="lose" class="bold center"></div>
```

When you lose, the text in the `win` div disappears and `You lose!` appears in the `lose` div. As you can see, `result` contains both `win` and `lose`. I figure one or both of these observations is important but I don't know how I would use an `if` statement to figure out whether a win or loss occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check to see if the [text](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#text-instance_method) is [included](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) within the respective <div>.  For example:

```
if browser.div(:id => "win").text.include? "You win!"
  puts "won"
elsif browser.div(:id => "lose").text.include? "You lose!"
  puts "lost"
else
  puts "something went wrong with the coin flip"
end
```

And a more simple example:

```
if browser.div(:id => "win").text.include? "You win!"
  puts "won"
else
  puts "lost"
end
```

For more info on conditional control structures, check out the If and Unless Expressions section in the [Expressions](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html) chapter of [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/).

Comment: Thanks, mate. This is the simple answer I was looking for. I had tried to use".text =" instead of ".text.include?" This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea:

```
<% if @result.heads? %>
  <div id="win" class="bold center">You win!</div>
<% else %>
  <div id="lose" class="bold center"></div>
<% end %>
```

This depends on your result model looking something like this:

```
class Result

  def initialize
    @heads = [true, false].sample
  end

  def heads?
    @heads
  end

  def tails?
    !heads?
  end

end
```

Comment: I just started Ruby two days ago, so sorry for the question, but how would I get it to print in the console "You win" or "You lose"? I'm not quite sure what your if statement actually does. Would I replace <div id="win"...> with "puts 'You win!'" and the other one with "puts 'You lose!'"

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Since only one div (win/lose) contains text at a time, is there a simpler way which would be to check if the div is empty? How would I do that?